# bigquery - left join on most recent record in the right table without going over timestamp of left table

Tags: google-bigquery

So I have a table of purchases:
user_id
purchase_time
amount

And I have a table of the user activities on the website:
user_id
location
browse_time

How can I join the purchases table with the activities table to get the most recent browse_time activity without going over the purchase_time?

For example if I have for Purchase Table:

```
user_id     Purchase_time          amount
-------     -------------------    ------
1           2012-12-13 12:30:00    $20
2           2012-12-14 23:00:00    $50
```

And I have the Activities Table:

```
user_id     browse_time            location
-------     -----------            ---------
1           2012-12-14 23:00:00    Product 3
1           2012-12-13 12:00:00    Product 1
1           2012-12-13 11:30:00    Product 2
2           2012-12-15 00:00:00    Product 5
2           2012-12-14 22:30:00    Product 7
2           2012-12-14 20:00:00    Product 6
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
user_id    purchase_time           browse_time           location     amount
-------    -----------------       ---------------       ----------   -------
1           2012-12-13 12:30:00    2012-12-13 12:00:00   Product 1    $20
2           2012-12-14 23:00:00    2012-12-14 22:30:00   Product 7    $50
```

I tried mysql syntax and it didn't work.  I know that bigquery does not allow "<" or ">" for join statements on "on".   So is that even possible to do it in Big Query?

Answer (score 1):

So if you do something like this, you'll get a lot more result than you want:

```
SELECT
    user_id
    purchase_time
    browse_time
    location
    amount
FROM
    purchases pur
JOIN
    user_activities uav
ON
    pur.user_id = uav.user_id
```

You want the MOST RECENT of user_activities, so lets make a subquery of the right side of the join:

```
SELECT
    user_id
    purchase_time
    browse_time
    location
    amount
FROM
    (SELECT 
         user_id AS user_id 
         location AS location
         MAX(browse_time) AS browse_time 
     FROM
         purchases 
     GROUP BY user_id,location) pur
JOIN
    user_activities uav
ON
    pur.user_id = uav.user_id
```

I hope this will helps you solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you Balazs.  Unfortunately that would return the most recent, not the most recent activity that happened before the purchase (there are no filters for it in your query).   Also there isn't the ability to get the one location before the purchase, not all the locations the purchaser has seen before (and in your case, after also) the purchase.   What can I do to filter the results further.   Currently I am running something similar but the result is too large to return.

Comment: you can add a where clause e.g. `WHERE pur.browse_time < uav.browse_time`.

Comment: Hi Jordan, so add the clause would get every uav time that is greater than  the purchase time.   Is there are way to just get the last one that is less than the purchase time without going over the time?   Just a one to one relationship between the two tables?